# 'Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory' With spEl annotation

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to have a programmation for the next 7 days. Before I used dateadd in my query by I am using a mysql database, and it is not working,

So I tried to use spEl annotation to use it, but I have this error :

'Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory'

Do you have a solution of this problem or an alternative to have the same result ?

```
public interface ProgrammationRepository extends JpaRepository<Programmation, Long> {
    @Query("select programmation from Programmation programmation left join fetch programmation.film where programmation.dateprogrammation >= ?#{@ProgrammationRepository.addSixDay()} and programmation.dateprogrammation <= ?#{@ProgrammationRepository.addSevenDay()}")
    List<Programmation> getSevenNextDay();

    @Query("select programmation from Programmation programmation left join fetch programmation.film where programmation.film.id = :id")
    List<Programmation> getFindByFilm(@Param("id") Long id);

    default Instant addSixDay() {
        System.out.println( Instant.now().plus(6, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
        return Instant.now().minus(6, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    }

    default Instant addSevenDay() {
        return Instant.now().plus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

spring default bean names are lowercased. So you may need to try `#{programmationRepository.addSevenDay()}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#{@ProgrammationRepository.addSevenDay()}
```

The above SpEL means that it will find a bean whose name is ProgrammationRepository and invoke its `addSevenDay()` method.

However , the name of `ProgrammationRepository` bean is **p**rogrammationRepository  but not **P**rogrammationRepository (Default name of a spring bean is the lowerCamelCase of the class name).Change the SpEL to the following should fix the problem:

```
#{@programmationRepository.addSevenDay()}
```

Alternatively , you can change the name of `ProgrammationRepository` bean to ProgrammationRepository by:

```
@Repository(value = "ProgrammationRepository")
public interface ProgrammationRepository extends JpaRepository<Programmation, Long> {

}
```